# Show message "no score entered" if user inputs a specific number into a prompt

Tags: javascript, html

Currently my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkwrz79p/) allows a user to input some exam scores one number at a time and shows the average and total score for the numbers they give. Currently, if they enter -999 into the box, it means they are finished entering numbers and the average and total can be calculated.

**How can I edit this to make it so that if the user entered -999 as their first input it displays “No score entered.”?**

```
<script>

function userInput() {

  var examScores = 0;
  var totScores = 0;
  var i = 0;
  var scores = [];

  while (true) {
    examScores = parseInt(prompt("Enter a score or enter -999 when you're finished: "));

    if (examScores === -999 && scores.length === 0) {
      document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML = "No score entered.";
      break;
    }

    else if (examScores === -999) {
      break;
    }

    else {
      scores.push(examScores);
      i++;
    }
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    totScores = totScores + scores[i];
  }

  document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML = "<h1> The sum of these scores is: "+totScores.toFixed(2)+"<br/> The average of these scores is: "+(totScores/scores.length).toFixed(2);
}

</script>

<h1>Exam Scores</h1>
<h3>Click to enter scores</h3>
<input type="button" value="Enter student scores" onclick="userInput()" />
<div id="scores"></div>
```

Comment: You should return from the function immediately when no scores are entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return instead of just breaking the loop.

```
if (examScores === -999 && scores.length === 0) {
  document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML = "No score entered.";
  return;
}
```

Breaking the loop solely will cause the function execution to continue, hence *always* reaching

```
document.getElementById("scores").innerHTML = "<h1> The sum of these scores is: "+totScores.toFixed(2)+"<br/> The average of these scores is: "+(totScores/scores.length).toFixed(2);
```

Since the above line is being executed, your own work will be overwritten. Returning from within the loop would end the execution of the function.